# How to make sure that my service is always up and running

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have created a service in Windows and set enteries in Registry so that the service automatically starts on log on.

Now the problem is that in Task manager->Services field, my service's status is Running for only 2-3 minutes after log-on.

After this time my service status turns to Stopped, and it never again switches to running.
It also doesnot do its designated work.

I want to know that what changes in Registry or the Properties of the service can be made to make sure that service is always running.

Comment: If your service stops running, it means that all of its threads have exited, either deliberately, or because of unhandled error conditions. As such, it's a fault in your code, rather than something that has to be set in windows, and we can't fix it from just a description. Are there any messages in the event log re: unhandled errors in your service?

Comment: None, nor should there be. What if an admin wants to stop it? DEal with why it's stopping as others suggested. Then make sure your consumners can properly detect it isn't there and give the cklient a clue as how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are getting an unhandled exception which is shutting down the process.

You need to add logging to your windows service - something that will write all exceptions to the event log is a fairly common thing to do.

This will allow you to see why the service is stopping. At this point you will hopefully have enough information to fix the coding error.

> I want to know that what changes in Registry or the Properties of the service can be made to make sure that service is always running.

Well, assuming the issue is with your service, there is no configuration that will help.

Comment: Thanx All for the replies..Actually i dont know how but now when i re-start my system, my service doesnot start at all. First its status is 'Starting' and then it directly becomes 'Stopped' When i looked at the EventViewer, it says that 'The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion' with EventID : 7000 and

Comment: and

'A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the KeyLogger service to connect' with EventID : 7009

Any Help is greatly Appreciated

Comment: @PankajVatsa - What is the `KeyLogger` service? It didn't start.